# Only Return Highest Value for another unique Column

Tags: mysql

Preferably without downloading the entire database and scanning each item, is there a MySQL query that could access this table:

```
__________________________________
|   ColID   |      Timestamp      |
|___________|_____________________|
|_____2_____|_2012-08-01_12:00:00_|
|_____1_____|_2012-08-01_12:01:00_|
|_____3_____|_2012-08-01_12:02:00_|
|_____3_____|_2012-08-01_12:03:00_|
|_____2_____|_2012-08-01_12:04:00_|
|_____3_____|_2012-08-01_12:05:00_|
```

And return only these rows:

```
__________________________________
|   ColID   |      Timestamp      |
|___________|_____________________|
|_____1_____|_2012-08-01_12:01:00_|
|_____2_____|_2012-08-01_12:04:00_|
|_____3_____|_2012-08-01_12:05:00_|
```

So as to extract only one of each `ColID` with the highest `Timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `MAX`:

```
SELECT   ColID, MAX(Timestamp) AS Timestamp
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY ColID
```

---

Also, just a tip you may want to keep in mind for the future: if you wanted to also select other columns that might be in the same table for each maximum `ColID`, you cannot select it directly in the above query due to the nature of `GROUP BY`. You will need to wrap the query in a joined subselect joining on both the id and date columns:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   tbl a
JOIN   (
       SELECT   ColID, MAX(Timestamp) AS max_timestamp
       FROM     tbl
       GROUP BY ColID
       ) b ON a.ColID = b.ColID AND a.max_timestamp = b.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can achive this by using `GROUP BY` with `MAX` as:

```
SELECT ColID, MAX(Timestamp) AS max_Timestamp      
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ColID;
```